# Как создать fake input stream и fake output stream?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mocking

Задание: протестировать метод main с использованием Junit. По схеме 1) fake input stream. 2) reverse mock. 3) fake output stream. Я создал мок для reverse. Метод пользовательского ввода у меня выведен в отдельный класс ReadText .Подскажите пожалуйста как зафэйкать класс вода и метод вывода . (Знаю что смысла нет в тестировании метода main но дана задача протестировать его в учебных целях ).

1. тестируем как отработал main.выловить проход по мейну до reverse и словить что выдаеться в system.out
2. делаем сетер в main чтобы можно было передать объект с тест класа
3. делаем мок чтобы словить что попадает а reverse
4. делаем мок и вылавливаем что попадает в system.out но reverse выдает статику - из серии проверяем весь маршрут без задева reverse метода.

Алгоритм решения есть, вопрос как это реализовать?

Исходный код:

```
public class Main {
    private static  Reverse reverse = new Reverse();
    
    public static void setReverse(Reverse reverse) {
        Main.reverse = reverse;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String OUTPUT_MESSAGE = "Reversed string:";
        
        String text = ReadText.readText();
        String reversedText = reverse.reverseText(text);
        System.out.println(OUTPUT_MESSAGE + reversedText);
    }
}



import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Reverse {
   
    private static final String DELIMITER = " ";

    public String reverseText(String text) {
        String[] words = text.split(DELIMITER);
        return Arrays.stream(words).map(this::reverseWord)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER));
    }

    public String reverseWord(String word) {
        char[] wordCharacters = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0, j = wordCharacters.length - 1; i < j;) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(wordCharacters[i])) {
                i++;
            } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(wordCharacters[j])) {
                j--;
            } else {
                char current = wordCharacters[i];
                wordCharacters[i] = wordCharacters[j];
                wordCharacters[j] = current;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(wordCharacters);
    }
}



import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadText {
    
    private static Scanner in;

    public static String readText() {     
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input string to reverse:");
        return in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Код теста:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MainTest {

    @Test
    void Maintest() {
        Reverse reverse = mock(Reverse.class);
        Main.setReverse(reverse);
        when(reverse.reverseText(("Hello World"))).thenReturn("olleH dlroW");

        assertEquals("olleH dlroW", reverse.reverseText("Hello World"));
        verify(reverse, times(1)).reverseText("Hello World");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.setIn` и `System.setOut`, но лучше параметризировать тестируемые классы потоками ввода-вывода, т.е. чтоб потоки можно было подменять в самом классе.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Вы имеете в виду перенести метод Scanner в main? А не в отдельный класс RadText как у меня. Правильно вас понял?

Comment: Добавил ответ с примером, как лучше всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример:

```
public class MainTest {

  public static class Main {
    InputStream in;
    PrintStream out;

    public Main(InputStream in, PrintStream out) {
      this.in = in;
      this.out = out;
    }

    void run() {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
      out.print(scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }

  @Test
  void testStreams() {
    ByteArrayInputStream testIn = new ByteArrayInputStream("aline\nnextline\n".getBytes());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream testOut = new PrintStream(baos);

    new Main(testIn, testOut).run();

    assertEquals(baos.toString(), "aline");
  }
}
```

Т.е. всю логику реализовать в методе класса, зависимости передавать в конструктор и в тесте передать тестовые потоки через конструктор.

В вашем случае имеет смысл и `Reverse` передавать, как зависимость. Тогда сам метод `main` будет выглядеть так:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main(System.in, System.out, new Reverse()).run();
}
```